# Find size of dynamic image list in flutter

Tags: flutter

**I am picking images from file manager in multiple before navigation them to other screen i want to check the total size of all the images **

*Here is my code *

```
List<dynamic> images;
try {
  /// initialize list
  selectedGalleryImages = [];

  images = await picker.pickMultiImage();

  /// get image
  if (images == null) return;

  /// check if no image selected
  if (images.length == 0)
    return;
  else {
    for (var x in images) {
      selectedGalleryImages.add(File(x.path).path);
    }
    /// navigate to other add new item page
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => AddItemsVC(selectedGalleryImages, false, null,
            null, null, null, "FromExplore")));
  }
} catch (e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to image file size means check this once.

```
double fileSize = 0;

for (var x in images) {
    selectedGalleryImages.add(File(x.path).path);

    final bytes = (await File(x.path).path.readAsBytes()).lengthInBytes;
    fileSize = fileSize + bytes;
}
```

Comment: The method 'readAsBytes' isn't defined for the type 'String'.

Comment: check this once
File image = new File('image.png');
print(getFilesizeString(bytes: image.lengthSync()}); // Output: 17kb, 30mb, 
// Format File Size. Function:
static String getFileSizeString({@required int bytes, int decimals = 0}) {
const suffixes = ["b", "kb", "mb", "gb", "tb"];
var i = (log(bytes) / log(1024)).floor();
return ((bytes / pow(1024, i)).toStringAsFixed(decimals)) + suffixes[i];
}

Comment: it is for single file not for list of files which one picks from glary or camera can you have any other solution

Comment: use same function in loop for all images. that's all.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer

```
        double sum = 0;
        double sizeInMb = 0;

        for (var x in images) {
          selectedGalleryImages.add(File(x.path).path);
          int sizeInBytes = File(x.path).lengthSync();
          sizeInMb = sizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024);
          sum += sizeInMb;
        }
        if (sum > 10) {
          return //what you want to do 
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).